# Find the Inverse function of $f$

Tags: calculus

> find the Inverse function of $f(x)=\dfrac{2x}{1+|x|}$

My Try :

$$y=\dfrac{2x}{1+|x|}$$

if $x>0$ :

$$y=\dfrac{2x}{1+x}\\y+yx=2x \\y+yx-2x=0\\x(y-2)=-y\\x=\dfrac{-y}{y-2}\\f^{-1}(x)=\dfrac{-x}{x-2}$$

if $x<0$ :

$$y=\dfrac{2x}{1-x}\\y-yx=2x \\y-yx-2x=0\\x(-y-2)=-y\\ x=\dfrac{y}{y+2}\\f^{-1}(x)=\dfrac{x}{x+2}$$

it is right ?

Comment: It's right with this obs: $f$ is has the same sign of $x$

Comment: how about $x=0$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and you can summarize both regions into a single answer

$$f^{-1}\left(y\right)=\frac{y}{2-\left|y\right|}$$

Note that your function is bijective only when taken $f:\left(-\infty,\infty\right)\rightarrow\left(-2,2\right)$, so the inverse is defined as $f^{-1}:\left(-2,2\right)\rightarrow\left(-\infty,\infty\right)$.

Comment: why ? how $f^{-1}=\dfrac{x}{2-|x|}$

Comment: Because both $x$ and $y$ have the same sign, so $f\left(y>0\right)=\frac{y}{2-y}$ and $f\left(y<0\right)=\frac{y}{2+y}$ - exactly as you've written.

Answer (score 1):

You can go directly $y=\dfrac {2x}{1+|x|}$ then $|y|=\dfrac {2|x|}{1+|x|}$

This allows to solve for $|x|$, indeed $(1+|x|)|y|=2|x|\iff |y|=(2-|y|)|x|\iff |x|=\dfrac{|y|}{2-|y|}$

Now reporting in the initial formula $x=\dfrac y2(1+|x|)=\dfrac y2\times\dfrac{2-|y|+|y|}{2-|y|}=\dfrac y{2-|y|}$